# How can I setup word synonyms in my model?

Tags: django, django-models

Django noob here. I'm building a dictionary/lexicon and want to link word synonyms to each other.

**models.py**

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.Charfield()

class Synonym(models.Model):
    word_from = models.ForeignKey(Word, blank=True, null=True, related_name="word_from")
    word_to = models.ForeignKey(Word, blank=True, null=True, related_name="word_to")
```

How do you get the related synonyms? I'm using a generic.DetailView. Is this also the correct way to make the connection between the words?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the purpose of `word_from` and `word_to`. But the simplest model for word and synonym can be achieved through one table as:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.Charfield()
    synonym = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True,
        related_name='synonyms')
```

Comment: Word_from and word_to were taken from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a word could have several synonyms and every synonym could also be synonymous to other words, you can use Django's [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical), referencing `self`.

Here's such an example:

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(...)
    synonyms = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the self reference. But in the admin now I can't add another synonym, just one. Any ideas?